# Prove that the product of a continuous function with a differentiable function is also differentiable

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given a function $g : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ differentiable such that $g(0,0)=0$ and a function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ continuous. Prove that $f\cdot g$ (the product of those functions) is differentiable in (0,0).

I have already prove that $\frac{\partial f g}{\partial x} (0,0) = f(0,0) \frac{\partial g(0,0)}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f g}{\partial y} (0,0) =f(0,0) \frac{\partial g(0,0)}{\partial y}$, so I guess I have to prove that $$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{|fg(x,y)-f(0,0) \cdot \left(\frac{\partial g (0,0)}{\partial x} x + \frac{ \partial g(0,0)}{\partial y} y \right)|}{||x,y||} = 0$$
But I don't find any "clean" way to do that. What I can tell is that $$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{|g(x,y)-\left(\frac{\partial g (0,0)}{\partial x} x + \frac{ \partial g(0,0)}{\partial y} y \right)|}{||x,y||} = 0$$
is true since g is differentiable by hypothesis. I also know that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y)=f(0,0)$ since f is continuous. So I would like to do something like $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{fg(x,y)}{||x,y||} = \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{f(0,0)\left(\frac{\partial g (0,0)}{\partial x} x + \frac{ \partial g(0,0)}{\partial y} y \right)}{||x,y||}$$
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}f(x,y) \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{g(x,y)}{||x,y||} =f(0,0) \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\left(\frac{\partial g (0,0)}{\partial x} x + \frac{ \partial g(0,0)}{\partial y} y \right)}{||x,y||}$$
And since f is continuous $lim{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{f(x,y)}{f(0,0)} = 1$.  $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{g(x,y)}{||x,y||} = \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\left(\frac{\partial g (0,0)}{\partial x} x + \frac{ \partial g(0,0)}{\partial y} y \right)}{||x,y||}$$
And then 
$$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{|g(x,y)-\left(\frac{\partial g (0,0)}{\partial x} x + \frac{ \partial g(0,0)}{\partial y} y \right)|}{||x,y||} = 0$$
 is true since g is differentiable. But this doesn't seem right, I'm specially not sure about "forgetting" of the absolute value (it kinda makes sense since the limit is equal to zero but still not sure).

Comment: Your formulas for the partial derivatives of the product $fg$ are false even for differentiable $f$.

Comment: I'm 100% sure that they are not. Actually the first part of the exercise was to prove that. See that that's only true if g(0,0)=(0,0).

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the $g(0,0)=0$ condition.